# How to align text in RichText area in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
                   text: '•   ',                                            
          
                   children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(text: list2[1],),
                   ],
          ),       
),
```

Here I want the `text: '•   '` to have `left-center` alignment.

What is the way to achieve that?

Comment: can share any image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `Align`

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: '.  ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(text: list2[1],),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```